# Instance of a class that I don't inherit from in Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, inheritance, overriding

How can I create an Instance of a Class that I do not inherit from and override functions for it?

I Have I class called GetData and a viewController called SocialViewController.

```
@interface GetData : NSObject<NSURLConnectionDelegate> and

@interface SocialViewController:  UITableViewController<UITableViewDataSource>
```

Every time I try to create a instance of GetData in my SocialViewController implementation and override the functions it doesn't work and the functions in GetData are executed instead.

How can I create a instance of GetData in SocialViewController when SocialViewController inherits from UITableViewControler and not GetData?

```
@implementation SocialViewController

GetData myGetData;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    myGetData = [GetData alloc];

    NSString someString = @"my init string"

    [myGetData initWithValue:someString];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    //The method that I'm trying to override 
}
```

Comment: Show the code for what you've tried.

Comment: @implementation SocialViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    
    

    [super viewDidLoad];
    myGetData = [GetData alloc];
    NSString someString = @"my init string"
    [myGetData initWithValue:someString];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    //The method that I'm trying to override
}

Comment: I also created the variable myGetData just under the implementation keyword as GetData myGetData;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a class which is a subclass of `GetData` in order to override methods. So more like:

```
@interface MyGetData : GetData @end
@implementation MyGetData

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    //The method that I'm trying to override 
}

@end


@implementation SocialViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString someString = @"my init string";

    myGetData = [[MyGetData alloc] initWithValue:someString;
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.

One more thing though. 

I'm going to override this function dozens of different times. The only way to do this in Objective C is then to create dozens of different MyGetData subclasses?

Comment: No, there are many options. A better option is probably to modify `GetData` to have a block property. That block takes `NSURLConnection` (and / or `NSData`) as a parameter and is called form `connectionDidFinishLoading:`. Then when you instantiate `GetData` you set the block which contains the code you want to be run.

Comment: I  believe that what you want to do is use getData class to make get data asynchronously. i resolved this by sending the delegate as a parameter and executing the delegate method from the class that instantiate getData . Let me know if you are interested in this approach

Comment: @cromanelli, indeed, this is basically the same as the block approach. The delegate approach requires a protocol (similar to the block typedef) and setting the delegate (similar to setting the block instance).